# TaskStackBuilder vs normal startActivity again and again

Tags: java, android, android-intent, back-stack, taskstackbuilder

I am familiar with using **taskStackBuilder** that it keeps a fake backstack of your activities but i was wondering one thing that we can obtain this behavior by calling **startActivity()** again and again as per our requirement, then why should we use **taskStackBuilder** ?

Comment: Because it's better, and doesn't suffer from the problems that might happen when sequentially calling `startActivity()` when opening the app in the middle of some flow. "Opening the app" as in "starting the app from scratch"

Comment: another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912325/why-do-we-use-the-taskstackbuilder

Comment: make sense, right